# O que é o botão de "Participação"?

Tags: suporte

Hoje eu abri o Stack Overflow, fui no meu perfil e encontrei um botão novo (está presente também aqui no META) ao lado do **Perfil**. O que é esse botão ?

[image: imagem]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é um botão, é uma aba, que sempre esteve disponível na página, só mudou a estilização (mudou o CSS), e sim ficou feio, esquisito, confuso, como várias outra estilizações que fizeram nos últimos dias.

Essa página (ou região da página se considerar que o resto dela não muda), acessada clicando na aba, mostra tudo o que você fez no site, diferente da aba de Perfil que mostra só o seu perfil e um resumo da atividade. Obviamente que os detalhes de cada tip ode participação tem páginas mais específicas. A outra aba obviamente serve para editar o perfil e as configurações que você usa.

Em inglês o nome é Activity.

Comment: Eu tinha comentado na postagem passada, ficou muito feio, fora que não parece mesmo uma aba

Comment: Caraca, nem tinha percebido que era a aba de antes kkkkkkk Bugou minha mente essa estilização.